# c - merging two text files

Tags: c, winapi, file-io

Say I have 2 text files:

**A.txt:**

```
Param1: Value1
Param2: Value2
      .
      .
      .
      .
ParamM: ValueM
```

**B.txt**

```
Param1: Value1
Param2: Value2
      .
      .
      .
      .
ParamN: ValueN
```

- Number of parameters in **A.txt**, i.e. **M** can be greater than, lesser than or equal to the number of parameters in **B.txt**, i.e. **N**.
- Values for the same parameter need not be the same in **A.txt** and **B.txt**.
- **M** and **N** can probably reach a maximum value of 200.
- The parameter names are arbitrary. They have no numbers. The above was just for an illustration.

My objective is to merge **A.txt** and **B.txt**. If any conflicts occur, I have a file/in-memory storage which dictates which one takes precedence.

For example,

**A.txt** could look like:

```
Path: C:\Program\Files
Data: ImportantInfo.dat
Version: 1.2.3
Useless: UselessParameter.txt
```

and

**B.txt** could look like:

```
Path: C:\ProgramFiles
Data: NotSoImportant.dat
Version: 1.0.0
Useful: UsefulParameter.txt
```

The final text file should look like:

```
Path: C:\ProgramFiles
Data: ImportantInfo.dat
Version: 1.2.3
Useful: UsefulParameter.txt
```

Now my approach to thinking about this is:

```
get a line from A.txt
get a line from B.txt
tokenize both by ":"
compare param names
if same
    write A.txt's value to Result.txt
else if different
    write A.txt's line into Result.txt
    write B.txt's line into Result.txt  /* Order doesn't really matter */
repeat above steps until end of both text files
```

This approach doesn't take care of when **A.txt** has a certain parameter and **B.txt** doesn't. It would be extremely helpful if some lightweight library/APIs exist to do this. I am not looking for command-line tools (thanks to the overhead of doing `system()` calls).

Thanks!

Comment: why not just use BeyondCompare?

Comment: Why does `Useless` line of file `A.txt` not appear in final result?

Comment: This would be so much easier in a language that has a Map datatyp:
1. Read all of B and store in a Map.
2. Read all of A and store in the same map (automatically replacing any duplicates)
3. Output map to file.

Comment: @Aniket, Is the source code available?

Comment: Why do you want the source code of Beyond Compare? @AnishRam, it is a proprietary program.

Comment: @DidierTrosset, Because some parameters should not be there in the result. The parameters that should not be there are defined in another file (say).

Comment: I think this will be easy with bash script or some other scripting language.

Comment: @Aniket, How then would I integrate BeyondCompare into my code?

Comment: @Deanna, You are absolutely right. I was trying to think of all possible cases and probably got confused while laying down my description. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

This would be so much easier in a language that has a Map datatyp.
I would do it like this:

1. Read all of B and store the key-value strings in memory
2. Read A and for each key either overwrite the value (if it exists) or add it (if it doesn't)
3. Output the key-values to file

Comment: It would be *easier* to implement this with access to `std::map`, but even in C this approach will still work in general. You would just have to implement the name lookups and duplicate detection/replacements manually, that's all.

Comment: Yes, the algorithm is still a sound one. And for small files (up to a couple of thousand entries) there is no need to hash the keys.